# Please help me to build Hard Drop function (Tetris) using javascript

Tags: javascript, tetris

I'm trying to make Tetris using javascript.

https://github.com/meth-meth-method/tetris
-- I found this on Youtube and started to add some other functions.

I want to add Hard drop key in this Tetris game.

```
function playerDrop() {
    player.pos.y++;
    if (collide(arena, player)) {
        player.pos.y--;
        merge(arena, player);
        playerReset();
        arenaSweep();
        updateScore();
    }
    dropCounter = 0;
}
```

This is just normal drop function.
How to make a hard drop function out of it?

Comment: What is a hard drop function?

Answer (score 1):

I presume by 'Hard Drop' you mean to drop to the bottom on one key press?

If so, perhaps the follwing.

```
function playerDropHard() {
    while (!collide(arena, player)) {
        player.pos.y++;
    }
    player.pos.y--;
    merge(arena, player);
    playerReset();
    arenaSweep();
    updateScore();
    dropCounter = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly!